# Batch script does not recognize Windows environment variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have batch script like this, let's say test.bat. What it does is: cd into a directory path, and apply "make" commands:

```
set path=%SRC_PATH%
echo %path%


cd /d %path%
make clean
make all
```

When I run test.bat  from a Windows Command Shell, I get following error despite I defined path to make.exe in Windows Environment Variable

> 'make.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Note, I do not see this issue, when I use Windows command line and entered all the commands manually. Issue is only when I put the commands into a batch file.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to write this

set path=%SRC_PATH%
echo %path%

cd /d %path%

Just enter the path of make.exe in PATH Variable in environment variables..
PATH Variable already carries value so just add semi colon to the end enter the full folder path of make.exe(JUST FOLDER PATH)

now just calling make will work.

Comment: Looks like `%SRC_PATH%` is actually the location of the source code files being built, not the location of `make.exe`.  Also, note that the OP said they'd already added `make.exe` to their environment variables.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Issue was this line: set path=%SRC_PATH%. It was overriding value of windows path variable. I just renamed it, and it worked!